# Different ways to communicate between OSGi bundles in servicemix

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

What are different ways to communicate between two OSGi bundles in ServiceMix other than using ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSGi services, EventAdmin, REST/SOAP, direct/seda in-memory endpoints in a Camel route.. 100's of other options.

Edit: A good way to think about bundles is that they are just "jars" of Java classes. If you want to do any interprocess communication, you need something to start-up or initialize the classes and then decide what appropriate interprocess communication best suits your use case. OSGi Services are good for things that do not need to go across a wire or between two servers. blueprint.xml provides a Spring-bean-like way of starting classes and other options include the REST/SOAP.. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want  sychronous/asychronous,  you can use Camel Direct/SEDA/VM component